# "AbortError: Blocked by Safe Browsing." when using the Filesystem Access API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, file-system-access-api

When I try to write any data to a file handle using the Filesystem Access API in Chrome `Version 110.0.5481.100` I get:

```
AbortError: Blocked by Safe Browsing.
```

I am saving a custom extension for my web app.

Question A: How do I prevent getting this error?

Question B: Can I disable it somehow with Chrome settings?

Related:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API

Comment: Note: my domain is served over HTTPS, is brand new, and is not listed at https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search